# Data not being displayed to table using tablesorterpager

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, tablesorter

I'm using the jquery tablesorterpager to display list of documents from db. The data from the backend returns this format and I'm unable to figure out how I'm gonna make this display into the table.

```
$('#docTable').tablesorterPager({
            container: $(".ts-pager"),
            cssGoto  : ".pagenum",
            removeRows: true,
            output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})',
            processAjaxOnInit: true,
            updateArrows: true,
            page: 0,
            pageReset: 0,
            size: 10,
            savePages: true,
            ajaxObject: {
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            ajaxError: null,
            ajaxUrl: 'fetch_documents?page={page}&size={size}',
            ajaxProcessing: function(data) {
                console.log(data.rows);
                var total, rows;
                total = data.total;
                rows = data.rows;
                return [ total, rows ];
            }
        });
```

Data returned from `fetch_documents` *rows object*

```
{id: "112233", code: "ABC123", sender: "Max", address: "#523 Some St."},
{id: "452550", code: "RTB552", sender: "Arc", address: "#797 Times St."},
```

Comment: The [`ajaxProcessing` function](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxprocessing) should be used to build the table. Open the link to read the docs.